# Custom SRS Geoserver

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wms

I have the following coordinate system:

```
PROJCS["unknown",
  GEOGCS["unknown",
    DATUM["Unknown based on Krassovsky, 1942 ellipsoid",
      SPHEROID["Krassovsky, 1942",6378245,298.3],
      TOWGS84[23.92,-141.27,-80.9,-0,0.35,0.82,-0.12]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],
 PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 78.05],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1],
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 4500000.0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing", -11057.63],
  UNIT["m", 1.0],
  AXIS["Easting", EAST],
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]
```

The contents of the binding file:

```
0.065
0
0
-0.065
49.55705772056555
2500.497853548167
```

gdalinfo:

```
:/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/i$ gdalinfo original.jpeg
Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF
Files: original.jpeg
original.jgw
Size is 17723, 10755
Origin = (49.524557720565554,2500.530353548166659)
Pixel Size = (0.065000000000000,-0.065000000000000)
Metadata:
EXIF_ColorSpace=1
EXIF_DateTime=2021:10:21 16:44:03
EXIF_ResolutionUnit=2
EXIF_Software=GIMP 2.10.18
EXIF_XResolution=(300)
EXIF_YResolution=(300)
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=JPEG
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left ( 49.525, 2500.530)
Lower Left ( 49.525, 1801.455)
Upper Right ( 1201.520, 2500.530)
Lower Right ( 1201.520, 1801.455)
Center ( 625.522, 2150.993)
Band 1 Block=17723x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Overviews: 8862x5378, 4431x2689, 2216x1345, 256x155
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 2 Block=17723x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Overviews: 8862x5378, 4431x2689, 2216x1345, 256x155
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 3 Block=17723x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Overviews: 8862x5378, 4431x2689, 2216x1345, 256x155
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=JPEG
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When viewing the world image in this coordinate system, I get a white square, there is no picture itself, but the coordinates in the url are substituted correctly.
however, if I set the parameter false_easting = 3900000, then I start to see a cropped picture. If 3800000, then I see an even larger part of my picture. If 2500000, then the whole picture.

What might this be related to?

I can't leave false_easting equal to not 4500000, because otherwise the coordinates are incorrect.

Comment: to debug this would require access to the image and world file. - what does `gdalinfo` give for the image

Comment: The picture is too big (>100MB) to attach. The rest is attached in the question

Comment: are you sure the origin is right?

Comment: what is Origin?

Comment: the top left hand corner of your image (49.524557720565554,2500.530353548166659) - the X value is very small

Comment: how can I check it?

Comment: I have another image (12MB) in the same coordinate system, with a different anchor file. There Origin = (79.677729387837871,67.100760245079556) and still a white square

Comment: have you tried converting the image to a geotiff with a well known CRS?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works, but the picture has grown from 30 megabytes to 524. Is it possible to avoid this? and is there still a working way without conversions?

Comment: did you compress the geotiff? `-CO compress=JPG` http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html